# How do I add a reset option to this game?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want players to be able to press "r" after dying and be able to restart. I think I'm supposed to put my entire code into a reset method, but I am only a beginner, and I'm not quite there yet.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    private BodyPart b;
    private ArrayList<BodyPart> snake;

    private Apple apple;
    private ArrayList<Apple> apples;

    private Random r;

    private int xCoor = 10, yCoor = 10;
    private int size = 20;

    private boolean right = true, left = false, up = false, down = false;

    private int ticks = 0;

    private Key key;

    public Screen() {
        setFocusable(true);
        key = new Key();
        addKeyListener(key);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        r = new Random();

        snake = new ArrayList<BodyPart>();
        apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();

        start();
    }

    public void tick() {
        if(snake.size() == 0) {
            b = new BodyPart(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
            snake.add(b);
        }

        if(apples.size() == 0) {
            int xCoor = r.nextInt(80);
            int yCoor = r.nextInt(80);

            apple = new Apple(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
            apples.add(apple);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < apples.size(); i++) {
            if(xCoor == apples.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor ==          apples.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                size++;
                apples.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < snake.size(); i++) {
            if(xCoor == snake.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor ==  snake.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                if(i != snake.size() - 1) {
                    stop();
                }
            }
        }

        if(xCoor < -1) xCoor = 80;
        if(xCoor > 80) xCoor = -1;
        if(yCoor < -1) yCoor = 80;
        if(yCoor > 80) yCoor = -1;

        ticks++;

        if(ticks > 250000) {
            if(right) xCoor++;
            if(left) xCoor--;
            if(up) yCoor--;
            if(down) yCoor++;

            ticks = 185000;

            b = new BodyPart(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
            snake.add(b);

            if(snake.size() > size) {
                snake.remove(0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(new Color(10, 50, 0));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH / 10; i++) {
            g.drawLine(i * 10, 0, i * 10, HEIGHT);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT / 10; i++) {
            g.drawLine(0, i * 10, WIDTH, i * 10);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < snake.size(); i++) {
            snake.get(i).draw(g);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < apples.size(); i++) {
            apples.get(i).draw(g);
        }

    }

    public void start() {
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this, "Game Loop");
        thread.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        running = false;
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            tick();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private class Key implements KeyListener {


        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int key = e.getKeyCode();

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && !left) { 
                up = false;
                down = false;
                right = true;
            }

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !right) { 
                up = false;
                down = false;
                left = true;
            }

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && !down) {
                left = false;
                right = false;
                up = true;
            }

            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && !up) {
                left = false;
                right = false;
                down = true;
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One thing you can do is put what you have in `Screen()` into an initialization function. Then simply call that inside `Screen()` and your reset function.

Comment: So I couldn't find the check where user died. However all you would have to do is stop() and start().  Or did you want to restart the game with the gameloop thread still going?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < snake.size(); i++) {
            if(xCoor == snake.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor ==  snake.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                if(i != snake.size() - 1) {
                    stop();

Comment: that is the code to stop the snake, but I'm going to be honest I don't know what a gameloop thread is reallt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your code as follows:
I've added comments to explain my modifications

```
//this resets the position/size of the snake and clears the array
public void reset() {
    snake.clear();
    apples.clear();
    xCoor = 10;
    yCoor = 10;
    size = 20;
    running = true;
}


private class Key implements KeyListener {
    //reset when you are dead and the user presses r
    if (!running && (e.getKeyChar() == 'r' || e.getKeyChar() == 'R')){
        reset();
    }
}


public void tick() {
    while (running){

        //prev code

        for(int i = 0; i < snake.size(); i++) {
            if(xCoor == snake.get(i).getxCoor() && yCoor ==  snake.get(i).getyCoor()) {
                if(i != snake.size() - 1) {
                    //don't kill the process, just stop the game and wait for the user to press 'r'
                    //you may need to do additional stuff here
                    running = false;
                }
            }
        }

        //remaining code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes you are on the right track. The best way is to put the initilization code (setting all variables to their initial values) in a seperate method. Then when you press 'r' you simply call this method and it will 'reset' itself.

To make this happen you should do ALL variable initializations at the start. Currently you initialize `b = new BodyPart(xCoor, yCoor, 10);` in `tick()`. Since this only ever happens once (when the game started) this is better to put in your initilization method.

A rough proposal of an initilization method:

```
public void initialize() {
    snake = new ArrayList<BodyPart>();
    apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
    b = new BodyPart(xCoor, yCoor, 10);
    snake.add(b);
}
```

This method initializes all variables that are 'resettable'. You can then call this method when the `int key = e.getKeyCode();` is `KeyCode.R`.

Comment: How do I call that method and where do I put it. Thanks for the help

Comment: It's ok I fixed it, thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.